# Picker result is always nil

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Here is my picker controller coordinator. On my device, I can select a video but when it breaks in the debugger, `url` is always `nil`. Do I need to ask for permission?

```
class ImagePickerCoordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    @Binding var isShown: Bool
    @Binding var url: URL?

    init(isShown: Binding<Bool>, url: Binding<URL?>) {

        _isShown = isShown
        _url = url
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        let url = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL]

        isShown = false
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {

        isShown = false
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

The error is that the url must be cast using `as! URL`. No cast or `as? URL` doesn't work. Why is this? The original value is `Any?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    if let url = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? URL {
         self.url = url
    }

    isShown = false
}
```